# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' (Wordpress functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, php-parse-error

I have been creating a module for visual composer plugin, however, when I already have all the code mounted and saved in the `functions.php` file, I get the following error:

`syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'  - line 72`

I have looked to see if it is that by chance some `,` `;` or `)` was missing, but I do not find any missing.

This is the code of function:

```
function create_vc_adproducttag() {

  vc_map( array(
        "category" => "Myshortcodes Woocommerce",
        "name" => "Productos por etiquetas",
        "base" => "product_tag",
        "description" => "Este módulo incorpora productos pertenecientes a cualquier etiqueta",
        "show_settings_on_create" => true,
        "class" => "vc-adproducttag",
        "icon" => "",
        "params" => array(

                            // Campo para las etiquetas
                            array(
                                "heading"       => "Etiquetas",
                                "type"          => 'autocomplete',
                                "param_name"    => 'tags',
                                "description"   => "Elige las etiquetas de las que quieras que se muestren los productos",
                                "admin_label"   => true,
                                'value'             => '',
                                'settings'          => array(
                                        'multiple'          => true,
                                        'sortable'          => true,
                                        'unique_values'     => true
                                ),
                                'description'       => ''
                            ),


                            // Campo para las columnas
                            array(
                                "heading"       => "Columnas",
                                "type"          => "textfield",
                                "param_name"    => "columns",
                                "description"   => "Número de columnas por fila",
                                "value"         => "5",
                                "admin_label"   => true,
                                'edit_field_class'  => 'vc_col-sm-6 vc_column clear'
                            ),


                            // Campo para el operador
                            array(
                                "heading"           => "Operador",
                                "type"              => "dropdown",
                                "param_name"        => "operator",
                                "description"       => "Elige el operador que quieres",
                                "value"             => array(
                                        esc_html__('' )     => 'Ninguno',
                                        esc_html__('IN')        => 'Dentro de la etiqueta...',
                                        esc_html__('NOT IN')        => 'Fuera de la etiqueta...',
                                        esc_html__('AND')       => 'Dentro de las siguentes etiquetas...',
                                "admin_label"       => true
                            ),


                            // Campo para productos por pagina
                            array(
                                "heading"           => "Productos por página",
                                "type"              => "dropdown",
                                "param_name"        => "per_page",
                                "description"       => "Elige cuantos productos quieres que se muestren por página",
                                "value"             => array(
                                        esc_html__('-1' )       => 'Todos',
                                        esc_html__('12')        => '12',
                                        esc_html__('24')        => '24',
                                        esc_html__('36')        => '36',
                                "admin_label"       => true
                            ),

                    )
) );

}
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'create_vc_adproducttag' );
```

Could someone tell me the cause of this error?

Maybe it's just that my eyes are playing tricks on me and something important is missing in the code...

I would appreciate any help possible.

Thank you very much.

/******** EDIT: *****/

I have already found the error.

The problem is that I'm missing 2 `);` after array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Please do not answer your question in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrays whose parenthesis are opened right below `// Campo para el operador`  and below `// Campo para productos por pagina` seem to miss their closing parenthesis...

Comment: Si, de hecho, revisando nuevamente el código, he visto que faltan dos cierres de array y cuando vine a editar la publicación, vi su respuesta. :)
Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome - but actually I don't speak Spanish ;-) (but knowing Italian, I understood approximately what you wrote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is before add_action call:

) ))); instead of ) );